# Pass a pointer on default typed value as argument in one line

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, default-value, void-pointers

How can I pass a pointer to a default value of a particular type as argument?

My function expect:

```
void my_function(void* value);
```

This work:

```
auto value = int8_t();
my_function(&value);
```

This doesn't work:

```
my_function(&int8_t());
```

Same for this:

```
my_function(&(int8_t()));
```

How can I pass a pointer to the default value of a particular type (`int8_t` in my example) in one line?

Comment: You can't get the address of an rvalue.

Comment: you should be happy that the compiler rejects that, because it is wrong

Comment: You should add overload taking no parameters supplying default value `void my_function(void){int8_t default_value{}; return(my_function(::std::addressof(default_value)));}`

Comment: `auto value = int8_t(); my_function(&value);` Here you go: in one line. ;)

Comment: a more fundamental question: Does the parameter really need to be a pointer, and non-`const`? A `const&`, or of course a simple value, would let you pass a temporary.

Comment: what is the point of that parameter anyhow? passing `void*` without `const` only makes sense if the function is supposed to change the value, but if you pass a temporary there is no way to inspect that value after the function call. Either make it `const` or dont pass anything (and provide a `nullptr` default argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just get an address of temporary, so it won't work for you. Instead you can create a helper template function to return a default value of a desired type:

```
template <typename T>
const T *defval()
{
    static const T value;
    return &value;
}
```

Actually it means, that compiler will generate one `static` default variable per each type you use in `defval` function in your code. So, it's exactly what you want.

Then you can use it like:

```
my_function(defval<int8_t>());
```

Note, however, that you should change the signature of your `my_function` to:

```
void my_function(const void* value);
```

`const` is required here to guarantie that internal `static` value inside template function won't be changed and will remain default.

So, final code is:

```
void my_function(const void *value)
{
    (void)value;
}

template <typename T>
const T *defval()
{
    static const T value;
    return &value;
}

int main()
{
    my_function(defval<int8_t>());
    return 0;
}
```